# PHP max upload setting borked my WAMP stack

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wamp, php-ini

i was trying to increase the max upload in my wordpress config and tried the following:

add this to top of `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

that didn't work so i deleted it. then i tried this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

first, i put it in a blank php.ini file in my wp-admin folder and that didn't work, so i then added it to the php.ini file found in my `WAMP > php folder`, but then realized WAMP reads the `php.ini` from the Apache folder, so i added the two lines to the `php.ini` in the apache dir (which i end up opening using the WAMP admin panel so i'm sure it's the one WAMP is using (i think??)).

that didn't work either, and now, my web server isn't working at all. my website just has a blank page, phpmyadmin, and localhost are the same.

this is the common error i see in the apache logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8 bytes) in C:\\wamp\\www\\wp-load.php on line 31
```

any thoughts about what i screwed up?

i just noticed that WAMP is looking for the dll files under the folder "php5.5.12" and i only have "php5.4.12".  not sure how that happened.

Comment: Using the wampmanager menus is the correct way to edit the php.ini file from the correct location. You need to restart Apache every time you chnage the php.ini file so that it picks up your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you are working with WordPress. But the reason I am sending you this link is because the same rules apply:

https://drupal.org/node/207036
(This isn't just Drupal-centric.)

Try using these instructions to modify your php.ini or .htaccess files.